# Bitlocker Autounlock batch script for a flash drive with a password

Tags: batch-file

```
manage-bde  -on  -rp 111111-111112-111113-111114-111115-111116-111117-111118 E: -password "examplepass" -autounlock
```

What I am trying to do above is get it so that when run as it will start encrypting a flash drive (for me its always in E:), apply the recovery password, apply a regular password (IE when it is plugged in to a computer it doesn't know it will prompt for a password) and then have the flash drive autounlock on the machine the script is run on.

When I run the script as:

```
manage-bde  -on  -rp 111111-111112-111113-111114-111115-111116-111117-111118 E:
```

I get no issues and it encrypts correctly.

However, if I run it as I want to above it tells me that -autounlock and -password are not found or understood by command prompt.

Anybody know how to do what I want to do?

Comment: According to this `manage-bde -autounlock -Help`, `-autounlock` takes a required drive letter. I don't see a `-password` command at all. What OS?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit Enterprise. I got the -password parameter from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd875513%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: That parameter is for the `-on` parameter. I don't know this definitely but my guess is that they want you to do something like `manage-bde -on E: -password "examplepass" -rp 111111-111112-111113-111114-111115-111116-111117-111118`